# Issues converting a project from Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8 with plugins that are using Vaadin 7

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

I am converting a Vaadin 8 project to 7.  When I run the app the following messages is displayed:

```
   Widgetset 'com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet' does not contain an 
   implementation for com.vaadin.v7.ui.ProgressBar. Check the connector's 
@Connect mapping, the widgetset's GWT module description file and re-
compile your widgetset.
```

The component it is complaining about is a vaadin plugin

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>wizards-for-vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Inside "wizard-for-vaadin" plugin it is using import com.vaadin.v7.ui.ProgressBar;

**How do I get "wizard-for-vaadin" plugin to play nice with Vaadin 8?**

Comment: You will need to get a v8 version of the wizard-for-vaadin addon. Since this addon is serverside only, I think you could grab the sources and upgrade it to v8 yourself. (Something which is probably more difficult when it has client side code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For v7 compatibility when using server-side components, annotate your **UI** class with:

```
@Widgetset(value = "com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet")
```